# how to put a formula ontop of a rollup field summary?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

**Setup**

I have a Master-Detail relationship, and on the master, I sum up a field from the Detail object.

**Question:**

I need to allow the user to check a box on the master object which will add the sum by 1 or decrement by 1. How do I do this?

Here's what I've tried:

1. In an after update trigger on the master increment/decrement within the trigger. Of course I get an error:

   expected exception, contact your administrator: NonCashCompAfterUpdate: execution of 
    AfterUpdate caused by:
2. Created a new field, and used the existing field as a helper. Basically, I've hidden the old RFS while still using it. This works, but I wanted to see if there was a better way.

Before I went any further I wanted to check in for ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to directly alter values on a roll-up summary field in salesforce, except by altering the underlying detail records. The second proposal, as I understand it, would involve three fields, the roll-up summary, the checkbox, and the displayed summary (which would be a formula field). The displayed summary field would look something like this:

```
Rollup_Summary_Field__c + IF(Checkbox_Field__c, 1, -1)
```

The read-only nature of a roll-up summary field is preserved in Apex as well, so you would not be able to alter it through a trigger. Presumably, that is the nature of the error that you got, though the excerpt that you have attached omits the actual error.

Comment: you're right about the Read Only Nature of RFS being preserved in Apex. I did something like the formula you wrote. i think it was like  = (if_checked, RFS_C +1, RFS).... Thanks TM

Comment: @nivyaj at the moment there is no functionality to let roll-up summaries roll up multiple fields. You could theoretically use a trigger, but you would need triggers on both the master and detail and it would be non-trivial. The easiest solution (especially since you are already using a helper formula) would be to use two roll-up summaries and combine them in a formula field on the master object. Remember though, you are limited to 10 roll-up summaries per object.

Comment: Funny you should mention the idea of using 2 RFS, I looked into that, but you can't roll up a field on a master.  I think you're right about just using the formula that I did on Friday. I thought it best to exhaust all options before taking it to my boss. Thanks TM

Comment: Just as a FYI- The boss man agreed with the formula idea that I had last week. Thanks again TM